# iOS in-house application - distribution of SSL certificates

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, distribution, mdm

I've been researching a lot about an iOS application we're developing the last few months, and I've found this site to be invaluable. This is the first question I've not been able to find an answer to, so my sincere apologies if it exists.

It seems like the best option for us to distribute our application is via MDM. However, the application makes use of SSL certificates (currently a private key used as part of the authentication process, but it will also make use of a public key to identify the server in the near future). I'm looking for a good way to get those to the device.

The current method is to set up an HTTPS server and download them from within the app. I would rather push them out via MDM if that's possible, though. Unfortunately, the only way I can find to do that would be to create a custom .ipa file with the certificates included; I guess that's possible, as it's just a handful of high-profile users, but it's not ideal. Can you suggest a better method?

I'm also considering moving the certificate to the keychain, so that we can prevent it from being backed up to iTunes (which, according to currrent policy, could happen unencrypted, though I hope to change that as well). Any thoughts?

Best,
Lance

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to distribute the certificate via MDM then you will need to create a version of your app with the certificate in it indeed. While you can push a certificate by itself via MDM, that certificate would end up in Apple's name space in the keychain and thus no good for you.

Answer (score 1):

MDM is capable of pushing out bespoke configuration profiles. You could just embed the certificate in a profile, and push this out with MDM.